# if condition failing in batch script

Tags: if-statement, batch-file

I am new to batch and I am trying a script to install/uninstall zoom based on the installed version. It always executes second if condition even though the first one is true.

```
setlocal enableextensions
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /f "delims=" %%p in ('%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -Command "(Get-Item $env:Appdata\zoom\bin\zoom.exe).VersionInfo.FileVersion"') do set version=%%p
echo %version%

set "version=!version:,=.!"

if /i "%version%" LEQ "5.13.10.13305" goto Uninstall 
if /i "%version%" LSS "5.15.5.19404" goto Install
if /i "%version%" GEQ "5.15.5.19404" goto EnableLog
```

Comment: @SiKing I copied the same format, but somehow it changed after submitting

Comment: Without knowing **exactly** what `%version%` is displaying, an answer is likely to be a guess. Edit

Comment: Why pass information from PowerShell which requires further manipulation and comparison in the much less powerful language?

Comment: @Magoo %version% displays 5.13.7.12602

Comment: The comparison is character-by-character, so `5.13.7.12602` is GREATER than `5.13.10.13305`

Comment: @Compo using wmic for version is giving me error.

Comment: @Magoo help me out with the script please? I just don't seem to understand how to make it work!! Also, it's not always 5.13.7.12602. It changes on each user's machine.

Comment: I never mentioned using WMIC.exe! You're already using PowerShell, so get the version in the required format and make the comparisons using PowerShell too. If you get PowerShell to return an exit code according to whether it is `lt` `gt`, or `eq` then you won't need a `for /f` loop either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

SET "version=5.13.7.12602"

FOR /f "tokens=1-4delims=." %%g IN ("%version%") DO (
 SET /a major=100+%%g
 SET /a minor=100+%%h
 SET /a release=100+%%i
 SET /a build=100000+%%j
 SET "version=!major:~-2!.!minor:~-2!.!release:~-2!.!build:~-5!
)

SET version

if /i "%version%" LEQ "05.13.10.13305" echo Uninstall 
if /i "%version%" LSS "05.15.05.19404" echo Install
if /i "%version%" GEQ "05.15.05.19404" echo EnableLog

GOTO :EOF
```

The gymnastics are explained in the documentation ( `for /?` from the prompt) or hundreds of examples on SO.

Note that `enableextensions` and `enabledelayedexpansion` may be defined in the same statement. By default, extensions are enabled, but delayedexpansion is disabled.

It is only necessary to use the `!var!` syntax within a loop for variables whose values change within the loop. Use outside of a `code block` (parenthesised sequence of commands) can cause confusion as the programmer *expects* to find code to change the variable.

Hence, in your code, `set "version=%version:,=.%"` is quite valid as the statement is not in a block.

Note that for the version mentioned, BOTH of the first two statements are true. The code should have executed the `goto`, so if it's still attempting to execute both, there's something else wrong.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Magoo , It worked with little modifications as per the version numbers. Appreciate your help!